# Problem interacting with a webpage with selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium and Python to fill an input on this website :
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c40c393dc0f283f318791d746d894ddd3693572#readContract

To code is supposed to open collapsed tab number 5 and fill the input, but I get an error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='readHeading5']/a"}

```
driver.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c40c393dc0f283f318791d746d894ddd3693572#readContract')


time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='input_5_1']")
if len(elem) == 0:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='readHeading5']/a")
    element.click()
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='input_5_1']")

elem.send_keys('Your Username')
```

Comment: There are a *lot* of iframe elements in that document. Are you sure you're selecting the right one in your `driver.switch_to.frame(...)` call? Instead of locating the iframe using `find_element_by_tag_name`, consider using `find_element_by_id` instead. It looks like the iframe you want has a reasonable id.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do what you want. This uses
`find_element_by_id` exclusively, since in all cases the element we
want has a unique id attribute.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c40c393dc0f283f318791d746d894ddd3693572#readContract')


print('waiting for page load')
while True:
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("readcontractiframe")
    if iframe:
        break

    time.sleep(0.5)
print('page load complete')


driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
section = driver.find_element_by_id('readHeading5')
if section:
    section.click()
    input = driver.find_element_by_id('input_5_1')
    if input:
        input.send_keys('Your Username')

time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```